# How to download files with different extensions using Beuautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have built a web scraper in Python that takes a list of URLs and downloads a file on each page of that URL. When saving the file, the files do not have extensions (though they do open and are readable). It turns out there are several extension types: pdf, .rtf, and .docx. I need to know how to save the file with its original extension so I can better work with the files. The ultimate goal is to convert each file to .txt.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import os
import textract
import glob

#list of urls to visit
commission_links = pd.read_csv(list_of_urls)
url_list = commission_links['Url'].tolist()


for url in url_list:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    link_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'pull-right v-img dropdown icone-info bgc-comissao'})
    file_link = link_div.find('a')['href']
    file_response = requests.get(file_link, stream = True)

    #extract the file type from the file_link using split and indexing
    filename = os.path.basename(file_link)
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    print(extension)

    with open(f"file_{filename}{extension}", "wb") as f:
       f.write(file_response.content)
       print(f"File saved: file_{filename}{extension}")
```

Edit: to test solutions, here are some urls

```
commission_links = ['https://legis.senado.leg.br/comissoes/reuniao?reuniao=10944&codcol=50',
                    'https://legis.senado.leg.br/comissoes/reuniao?reuniao=10892&codcol=50',
                    'https://legis.senado.leg.br/comissoes/reuniao?reuniao=10891&codcol=50',
                    'https://legis.senado.leg.br/comissoes/reuniao?reuniao=10866&codcol=50',
                    'https://legis.senado.leg.br/comissoes/reuniao?reuniao=10844&codcol=50']
```

Comment: Please provide a couple of URLs so that others can test their solutions.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question to include some URLs and the correct div class tag.

Comment: As a general note on question writing, you don't need to post your exact unrunnable code - rather do a bit of hacking to make something that demonstrates the problem with a simple copy/paste. For instance, remove `import textract` - it is not acutally used but breaks the posted script. And instead of pd.read_csv, just use that url list in your example program. You call it "commission_links" but I think its supposed to be "url_list" ... and when I fix that, the example doesn't work because `file_link = link_div.find('a')['href']` doesn't find the 'a' tag.

Comment: Where I run your code with the URL lists i get `NONE` for  `link_div`.  What are you trying to extract?

Comment: You may find hints about the file type in `file_response.headers['Content-Type']`.

Comment: Code has been updated so that it is identifying the right link (original code had filler tag instead of correct: 'pull-right v-img dropdown icone-info bgc-comissao')

Comment: Yes. Thankfully, I have solved my issue and the answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `file_response.headers['Content-Type']` and then extract useful parts from a string:

The code below creates a string that stores the file type. By extracting only the parts of the string that come after the '/' and combining it with a "." one can create a string that has the correct file type extension.

```
extension1 = file_response.headers['Content-Type']
filename = os.path.basename(file_link)
extension2 = "." + extension1.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
print(extension2)
```

Next, we call the proper extension name when writing the file.

```
with open(f"file_{filename}{extension2}", "wb") as f:
   f.write(file_response.content)
   print(f"File saved: file_{filename}{extension2}")
```